# OpenVZ Ubuntu 13.04 VPS - unable to install MySQL

Tags: installation, server, mysql, lamp, vps

Today I bought a VPS from *edis.at*, [**OVZ Starter**](http://www.edis.at/en/server/linux-vps-solusvm-openvz/austria/ovz-starter/), and I installed *Ubuntu 13.04 x64* on it.

On a fresh install, running `apt-get install mysql-server`, freezes `apt-get`.

After setting the *MySQL root password*, I get this error: `Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user...`, and `apt-get` freezes. I can't even `CTRL-C` out of it.

I've reinstalled multiple times, but the same issue always happens. **What can I do?**

[Full shell log: from fresh install to freeze](http://pastebin.com/847V8FR8)

Comment: Did you try to re-install `mysql` after a system re-start?

Comment: @SauravKumar: I tried, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I don't know which way you tried to remove `mysql`! Although I suggest you to remove it with the configuration file using these commands: `sudo apt-get autoremove mysql-* && sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-*` then execute this once removed: `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean`. If everything works fine then execute and post the output of this command, which will find if you have any residual packages: `sudo dpkg -l | grep "^rc"` Now try to install `mysql` again by: `sudo apt-get -f install mysql-server mysql-client` Reply..

Answer (score 1):

This seems similar to the issue here:
['Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user' on a Openvz VPS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337934/unable-to-set-password-for-the-mysql-root-user-on-a-openvz-vps/410300#410300)

> ...it turned out to be a lack of memory issue. Running this script on
>   the host fixed it for me:

```
#!/bin/bash    
cid=104
vzctl set ${cid} --vmguarpages 1024M --save
vzctl set ${cid} --oomguarpages 1024M --save
vzctl set ${cid} --privvmpages 1024M:1024M --save
```

> Feel free to change 1024 to whatever amount of memory you want your
>   container to have. You will also need to change 104 to the ID of your
>   container.

As you are not the host, you will need to buy a bigger plan or upgrade your ram somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have something. It's not the most elegant solution, but it seems to work. I also have no idea what it does or why it works, I just found it [here](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=529).

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Let it display the error message. Assume that you can't Ctrl-C out of it, so just close your terminal and reconnect.

```
service mysql stop
nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

add this one line under the [mysqld] section - before [mysqldump])

```
innodb_use_native_aio = 0
```

Then run:

```
service mysql start
```

Now it should work. I recommend installing mysql-server by itself so it won't affect other installs when it crashes. It probably doesn't matter though.